# C# UWP, reusing geofences in geofencemonitor

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, geofencing

I'm developing UWP app which will assist people with public transportation in my city. It uses geofencing to notify when the device is near some station. All is working fine, but slow. On my lumia 830 it took 4-5 seconds to prepare data for all 250 geofences and create them. Since, geofencemonitor runs under system and can store my geofences even when my app is terminated, I thought it would be smart to not recreate all geofences again and again on every app startup, but create them once and then just reuse them.

But I cant figure out how. When I start my app, `Geofencemonitor.Current.Count` is 250 and `GeofenceMonitor.Current.Status` is Ready, but it never fires Geoface state changed event.

### My problem:

I m trying to reuse geofences in geofencemonitor. When I run my app and during startup *I **dont** call Geofencemonitor.Current.Geofences.Clear(); and then create and add all my geofences* -> geofence state change event is never fired.

**Edit:** It seems, that geofence status change fires only **once** after I add  geofence to geofencemonitor, independently on if the app was restarted or not. But "used" geofence still remains in geofence monitor. Does geofence have some supended state? Am I missing some geofence property?

Here is how I create geofence:

```
var geofence = new Geofence(id, geocircle, mask, false, dwellTime);

GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Add(geofence);
```

### My questions:

1. "Since, geofencemonitor runs under system and can store my geofences even      when my app is terminated" - Is this really true?
2. If my first questions is true, and it is possible to reuse geofences, what am  I doing wrong or do you know some place where I can go deeper into Geofencing in UWP?

Thanks for advice.

Here is how I listen geofences state change event:

```
ItsValueIs250 = Geofencemonitor.Current.Geofences.Count;
ItsValueIsReady = Geofencemonitor.Current.Status;
public async void OnGeofenceStateChanged(GeofenceMonitor sender, object e)
{
    var reports = sender.ReadReports();

    await Dispatcher.DispatchAsync( () =>
    {
        foreach (GeofenceStateChangeReport report in reports)
        {
            GeofenceState state = report.NewState;

            Geofence geofence = report.Geofence;


            if (state == GeofenceState.Entered)
            {
                stationInRange.Add(geofence.Id);
                StationInRangeCount = stationInRange.Count().ToString();

            }
            else if (state == GeofenceState.Exited)
            {
                stationInRange.Remove(geofence.Id);


            }
        }
    });
}
```

And maybe this method which I call during startup.

```
async public Task<string> GeomonitorInitialize()
{

    string message = string.Empty;
    var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
    switch (accessStatus)
    {
        case GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed:

            int i = 0;
            i = GeofenceMonitor.Current.Geofences.Count;
            return message;



        case GeolocationAccessStatus.Denied:
            message = "GeoDenied";
            return message;

        case GeolocationAccessStatus.Unspecified:
            message = "GeoError";
            return message;

        default:
            message = "Default";
            return message;
    }

}
```

I will add any piece of code I use as you will wish. Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue at this moment. The event only fires one time.